# Зачем в ARM разделение "mov" на "ldr" и "mov"

Tags: ассемблер, arm

Каким обрзом разделение функционала `mov` на три команды (`ldr`, `str`, `mov`) оптимизирует выполнение программы в ARM системах?

Answer (score 1):

В [RISC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC#%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_RISC) процессорах принято ограничивать операции с памятью выборкой инструкций, загрузкой данных из памяти в регистр (Load) и записью из регистра в память (Store).

Инструкции [ldr/str](https://www.realdigital.org/doc/ad2f32256366a7f6a39dde0113e5e665) это команды Load/Store.

Инструкция `mov` (это по сути макрос, который  раскрывается ассемблером в любой из  нескольких подходящих кодов операций (orr, add, mov..., ...)) переносит  непосредственный операнд, т.е. **констанату** в регистр (также, одна из форм MOV копирует один регистр в другой). Этот перенос может производиться со смещением, инвертированием и т.п. опрерациями, проводимыми над заданной константой ассемблером во время трансляции.

Не уверен, что тут можно говорить об оптимизации исполнения кода. Скорее, это разделение для програмиста. Если написано ldr/str, то обмен с памятью, все остальное это операции внутри процессора.